как заставить бота принимать команды моего селф-бота discord?
в моей ситуации нужно через self-бота discord отправлять несколько команд и взаимодействовать с другим, простым ботом. Но он не воспринимает команды отправленные через софт как команды. А как просто текст, хотя и присылается он с префиксом. Использую discord.py-self
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        rts_bot = client.get_user(1213028072945881129)
        await rts_bot.send('/blank')
        return


client.run('token')

